# In Laravel 5.4, how does the method 'protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)' work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In the Laravel file src\illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php, there is a method as follows -

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
```

This method seems to be redirecting the logged in user to a welcome logged in user page, but the method is blank. When I insert in this method 'return 'hello user';' then the page displays 'hello user'. I would like to change this method to redirect to a custom url and was wondering where I would be able to make the changes and study the rest of the code related to this method. I'm having difficulty locating the proper codes I'm looking for.

Edit: The above method is used in this method in the same file in the ternary code. I'm trying to figure out how they work together -

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: You should not mess with that in your `src\illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` it is core laravel file

Comment: hey Nikhil, could you help me out here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174928/laravel-5-4-how-do-i-redirect-logged-in-users-to-referral-url-after-successful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4, How do I redirect logged in users to referral URL after successful login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174928/laravel-5-4-how-do-i-redirect-logged-in-users-to-referral-url-after-successful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the class that handles that method is inheriting trait ..
if you would like a custom functionality on successful login .. what you can do is not use the laravel login function .. you can do your own login using the Auth facade ..

in your LoginController for example

```
function myOwnLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials= $request->only('username', 'password');
    if(Auth::attempt($appGrantCreds))
    {
        // in this block the user is already authenticated using username and password ..
        // so you can do your functionality here and whatsoever
    }
    else
    {
        // do your functionality for unsuccessful login
    }
}
```

and also dont forget to set the `$redirectTo = '/yourDesiredRoute';`