# Laravel 5.4, How do I redirect logged in users to referral URL after successful login?

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication

How do I redirect users after a successful login in Laravel 5.4 without editing the core files?

Comment: You can set `protected $redirectTo = '/yourroute';` in `LoginController.php`

Comment: Did you do `php artisan make:auth`and edit `protected $redirectTo` in LoginController generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about referral URL that you're passing as GET or POST parameter, you can catch referral URL parameter and save it to the session, for example:

```
session(['redirectAfterLogin' => request('referralUrl')]);
```

Then you can override `authenticated()` in `LoginController` (5.4) to check session and redirect the user:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (session()->has('referralUrl')) {
        $url = session('referralUrl');
        session()->forget('referralUrl');
        return redirect($url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the path to where you'd want to redirect after successful login in your [Login Controller](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php#L28)

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set protected `$redirectTo = '/yourroute';` in `LoginController.php`.

You don't have to edit core files, and you shouldn't edit it

Comment: @Simon Suh, Got it?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways

first is their answer .. using

```
$redirectTo = '/yourroute';
```

and as they mentioned it's not a good practice to change any scripts in laravel's core ..

if the first one didn't work, another way around, is to add a condition in your login/register form like

```
if(Auth::check())
{
    return redirect('/yourroute');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect them to the intended url.

*The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.*

For e.g:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

More in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)